# Making Data.Map a functor in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, functor

I'm studying the basics of Haskell from [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)

There is an exercise in the book where you need to make Data.Map into a Functor.

I'm trying to make my own functor typeclass and make Data.Map into an instance of it.

So here's what I tried:

```
import Data.Map as DataMap
import Data.List as DataList

    class MyFunctor f where
        myfmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

    instance MyFunctor (Ord k) => (DataMap.Map k) where
        myfmap f x = DataMap.fromList $ DataList.map (\(p,q) ->(p,f q)) $ DataMap.toList x
```

When I try to compile this, GHCI gives me this error:

```
`myfmap' is not a (visible) method of class `Map'
```

I tried looking around other SO answers, blogs, mailing list threads etc without much luck.

The only thing I found was the description of the error message in the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Error_messages#.22.60foo.27_is_not_a_.28visible.29_method_of_class_.60Bar.27.22) which says that GHCI throws this error when one tries to instantiate a class, but did not import the functions one tries to implement.

I have imported Data.Map and Data.List so I don't think that's the real cause.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that your `instance` syntax isn't quite right:

```
instance (Ord k) => MyFunctor (DataMap.Map k) where
    ...
```

Otherwise it seems fine.

Comment: Stupid me. That was it. Thanks!

Comment: `myfmap f = M.fromList . map (second f) . M.toList` hlint can help too

Comment: @TheInternet yup. Simpler than my current version. Thanks.

Comment: @AnupCowkur, this is a little more verbose, but more readable IMO. http://lpaste.net/98091

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M          

class Functor' f where                  
    fmap' :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b   

instance (Ord k) => Functor' (M.Map k) where
    fmap' = M.map
```

Comment: I honestly believe that Tom Savage's answer is more pedagogical, but I'm pretty sure that Miran was expecting something more along the lines of what I wrote (based on his code for a list as an instance of the Functor class).